# SOAP Server application is not running in Zend 2.0 while working perfectly on Zend 1.7

Tags: soap, zend-framework2

Does anybody have an idea about this issue or could somebody point me to a example SOAP server app code built in Zend 2.0.

Comment: can you post a little more info? Are you trying to run the same app on different versions? examples please